# VS for Mac not showing local git file diff

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac-2022

I typically develop on Windows, but I've recently been using the new Visual Studio for Mac 2022 release, which has a "Git Changes" window. Whenever I open my git repository in VS, in the Git Changes window it will say something like "this directory doesn't contain a Git repository" and offers to initialize one for me (which of course does nothing). From Googling around, it seems to be a "safe directories" issue, which I can get around with adding the directory to safe directories in Git config. This isn't always respected though, and half the time it will only show if I go to Git -> Commit or Stash, and then it will realize I'm in a git repo.

The bigger issue is that it *almost* never shows me the local file of the diff, like [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hreY1.png). It seems to know that there is a diff though, as you can see it does say "2 lines removed" at the top. Sometimes, randomly, if I click around and change the views it will actually show the correct diff. But it's impossible to reproduce, it will just randomly decide to show it or not. I would say maybe 1 out of 20 times it will work.

It's also showed me incorrect information in the Git Changes window, such as saying I deleted 6 local files, but I didn't, and once when I double-clicked a "deleted" file in the window, it opened the *correct* diff! You can see it falsely flagging the files as being deleted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I72IV.png).

I've tried restarting my Mac without any luck, and I've messed with the file/directory permissions quite a bit but it has no impact on how VS acts. I couldn't find anything in the logs that seemed to mean anything. I also tried re-cloning the git repo and that didn't solve it either.

I also can't seem to find anyone else with this issue. I'm on the newest version of VS for Mac, with macOS 12.5.1.

Any ideas??